# Algorithm or closed form solution that lets me directly compute the $n^{\text{th}}$ state of an LFSR?

Tags: lfsr

I have a large linear feedback shift register with a known state and taps.

Now I want to compute the state of the LFSR after $n$ iterations.

The problem: $n$ is in the order of $2^{256}$ so just brute forcing is not an option. Is there an algorithm or closed form solution that lets me directly compute the $n^{\text{th}}$ state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the initial state is $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_{k-1}$ and the recurrence relation is $b_k = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} a_ib_i$, then in linear-algebraic terms we have
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_k
\end{pmatrix} = U \begin{pmatrix}
b_0 \\ b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}, $$
and more generally
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
b_{n} \\ b_{n+1} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n+k-1}
\end{pmatrix} = U^n \begin{pmatrix}
b_0 \\ b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}, $$
where of course
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}. $$
And $U^n$ can be computed efficiently by standard exponentiation algorithms.

Comment: Addition: it is common to use a primitive polynomial for the LFSR; in that case, the LFSR repeats after $2^k-1$ steps, and it follows that  the $n^\text{th}$ state is also the $(n\bmod(2^k-1))^\text{th}$ state, and we can compute $U^{(n\bmod(2^k-1))}$. In the context of the question, it will help when the polynomial is of degree less than about 256.

Comment: However, before you rely on the optimization that fgrieu suggested, you have to make sure that the LFSR is indeed based on a primitive polynomial (or, more generally, a prime polynomial); if not, then taking the modulus will (likely) give you wrong results.  What fkraiem suggested works regardless of the primality of the polynomial.